# Pandas iterate over a DataFrame to get the values from columns according to conditions and put them in a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here are some lines from my DataFrame composed as follows :

```
Index ['TimeStamp'] ['ThreadID'] ['Start|End'] ['StepIdentifier']
1017 18:44:22,997 [12] Start FetchMasterData
1018 18:44:22,997 [12] Start GetSmrCalculatedMeterData
1020 18:44:22,997 [12] End GetSmrCalculatedMeterData
1021 18:44:22,997 [12] Start GetSmrPhysicalMeterData
1023 18:44:23,013 [12] End GetSmrPhysicalMeterData
1024 18:44:23,013 [12] Start GetSmrMarketDeliveryPointData
1026 18:44:23,013 [12] End GetSmrMarketDeliveryPointData
1027 18:44:23,013 [12] Start GetSmrMarketHeadpointData
1029 18:44:23,013 [12] End GetSmrMarketHeadpointData
1030 18:44:23,013 [12] End FetchMasterData
```

I need for each Thread to get the Start and End time for each process.
We can see that the "Start" and the "End" for a process (like FetchMasterData) do not necessarily follow each other.

In order to create a new DataFrame like this:

```
['ThreadID'] ['StepIdentifier'] ['Start'] ['End']
    [12]      FetchMasterData  18:44:22,997 18:44:23,013
```

I tried to compare a line that has a process start with all the following ones until I find the end of the process, then to create a line in the new dataframe :

```
def iterateDfStartEnd(df):
    df = createDataFrame() // Function to create the DataFrame shown above
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ThreadID','StepIdentifier','StartTime','EndTime'])
    j = 1013 // Because i starts at 1012(like j = i + 1) and i ends at 1140
    for i in df.index
        while(df.iloc[i,'End|Start'] == "Start" & df.iloc[j,'End|Start'] == "End"
        & df.iloc[i,'StepIdentifier'] == df.iloc[j,'StepIdentifier']
        & df.iloc[i,'ThreadID'] == df.iloc[j,'ThreadID'] & j < 1141):
            j += 1
        new_df['ThreadID'] = df.iloc[i,'ThreadID']
        new_df['StepIdentifier'] = df.iloc[i,'StepIdentifier']
        new_df['StartTime'] = df.iloc[i,'TimeStamp']
        new_df['EndTime'] = df.iloc[j,'TimeStamp']
        j = i + 1
    return new_df
```

For finally calculate for each process the time between the operations Start and End and to have a DataFrame like this (just for your information) :

```
['ThreadID'] ['StepIdentifier'] ['Time']
    [12]      FetchMasterData     16s
```

I don't understand how to iterate the dataframe by comparing rows as I do, I have errors with the indexes. Does anyone have another way to create the new dataframe ? Thanks everyone !

Edit :
Many thanks to the 2 proposed solutions but there is a problem, a "StepIdentifier" is not unique, it can appear several times in the DataFrame but with different start and end times

Like this :

```
['TimeStamp'] ['ThreadID'] ['Start|End'] ['StepIdentifier']
18:44:22,997 [12] Start FetchMasterData
18:44:22,997 [12] Start GetSmrCalculatedMeterData
18:44:22,997 [12] End GetSmrCalculatedMeterData
18:44:22,997 [12] Start GetSmrPhysicalMeterData
18:44:23,013 [12] End GetSmrPhysicalMeterData
18:44:23,013 [12] End FetchMasterData
18:44:23,013 [12] Start GGetSmrCalculatedMeterData
18:44:23,023 [12] End GetSmrCalculatedMeterData
```

We can see that the 'StepIdentifier' "GetSmrCalculatedMeterData" appears twice.

Here is a DataFrame to reproduce this display :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp': ['18:44:22,997','18:44:22,997','18:44:22,997','18:44:22,997','18:44:23,013','18:44:23,013','18:44:23,013','18:44:23,023'],
                'ThreadID': ['[12]','[12]','[12]','[12]','[12]','[12]','[12]','[12]'],
                'Start|End': ['Start', 'Start', 'End', 'Start', 'End', 'End', 'Start', 'End'],
                'StepIdentifier': ['FetchMasterData','GetSmrCalculatedMeterData','GetSmrCalculatedMeterData','GetSmrPhysicalMeterData','GetSmrPhysicalMeterData','FetchMasterData','GetSmrCalculatedMeterData','GetSmrCalculatedMeterData']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to have the same `StepIdentifier` for the same `ThreadID`, then you could try something like this:

```py
# sorting to make sure that the start and end time of the same process that took place on the same thread are one below the other
df = df.sort_values(by=['ThreadID', 'StepIdentifier', 'Timestamp'])

# assigning an inner group counter to distinguish same processes that took place on the same thread
df['group'] = df.groupby(['ThreadID', 'StepIdentifier', 'Start|End']).cumcount()

# unstacking to create the new columns
new_df = df.set_index(['ThreadID', 'StepIdentifier', 'group', 'Start|End']).unstack()
```

Attaching a screenshot of results for your MRE:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I don't understand your use of the pivot_table, it doesn't change anything in my DataFrame using your way

Comment: @TaborlinTheGreat I have modified my answer and it doesn't make use of a pivot table anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time but it doesn't work, I think it's because I have several times the same "StepIdentifier" that start and end differently. For example the DataFrame has several times the process "FetchMasterData" that starts and ends at different times. I have this error "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: @TaborlinTheGreat Can you provide some code that creates a minimal reproducible example? Having code to reproduce such a dataframe would further help us to test our solutions. You could, for example, create a dataframe where the same process exists 2 or more times for the same thread_id. This way we could see exactly what you mean and then it would be easier to solve it!

Comment: @TaborlinTheGreat Thanks for providing an MRE :-) I have tested my above solution with the code example you provided and it seems to work fine! I have attached a screenshot to demonstrate the results of my solution! If this is not the result you'd like please let me know!

Comment: I'm sorry, I have this error "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" with your solution, I'm trying to figure out how to fix this. But it's a great way to do it, thanks

Comment: @TaborlinTheGreat If you apply the solution on the sample dataframe that you provided in the description do you still receive the same error message? Or does it only happen when applying the solution on the original dataframe?

Comment: it works well with the small DataFrame I created but I have the error with the full one

Comment: I think I know why and the problem is with my file and not with the solution, I will investigate this

Comment: Let me know! My guess is that the solution should more or less work however! @TaborlinTheGreat

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly straightforward solution if your dataframe always has exactly one Start and one End time. You do a `.groupby()` on the ThreadId and the StepIdentifier, and then use the minimum of TimeStamp for Start and the maximum for End:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': ['18','19','20','21','22','23'],
                    'id': ['12','12','12','12','12','12'],
                    'se': ['Start', 'Start', 'End', 'Start', 'End', 'End'],
                    'event': ['stomp','cramp','stomp','break','cramp','break']})
g = df.groupby(["id",'event']).agg(Start = ('ts', lambda x: min(x)), End = ('ts', lambda x: max(x)))
g.reset_index()
```

The output looks like:

```
    id  event   Start   End
0   12  break   21  23
1   12  cramp   19  22
2   12  stomp   18  20
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the problem is that I have several times the same "StepIdentifier" for the same "ThreadID" that execute at different times. Is it possible to allow redundancy on the "StepIdentifier" for different start time with this solution ? So that I can for example have several times in the new DataFrame the process "FetchMasterData" that starts and ends at different times ?

Comment: I have edited my post for more information about this issue